# Filter by postal code as location within user defined radius

Tags: location, google-maps

I have to make a filter in which user will add postal code and select a radius. 
Suppose, user entered postal code = 12345 (which results into city 'XYZ') and the radius of 200 miles. So all nodes containing the location within the radius of 200 miles of the city 'XYZ' will be the output.

Can anyone suggest some solutions?

Answer (score 1):

[geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) should have what you're after.  It includes proximity handling and an exposable views filter.

Answer (score 0):

Views exposed filter with Proximity/Distance worked..... :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer so that it would be helpful for future readers :)